# Characters combination can't be restored from file to mySQL

Tags: mysql, cmd

There is a file `1.sql` with:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `tbl`;
CREATE TABLE `tbl` (
  `row` varchar(100) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `tbl` VALUES ('—\'');
```

This sql works fine when I run it in phpMyAdmin.

But when I run it from cmd:

```
mysql -u root -p dtbs < 1.sql
```

it fails

```
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 6: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''鈥擻'')' at line 1
```

If you change anything in `—\'`, it works. If you add letter between `—` and `\'` it works: `—d\'`

What is so special in `—\'`? Why I cannot use it from file in cmd (windos7-64). It is part of a dump which I am trying to restore.

Comment: can you try `type 1.sql` in `cmd` ?

Comment: `INSERT INTO tbl VALUES ('鈥攄\'');` encoding problems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running the command `chcp 850` in `cmd` before you run your code.

That will make the `1.sql` file load with correct encoding.

Comment: `type 1.sql` is still messed, but mysql restores dump without errors.

Answer (score 0):

`--default-character-set=utf8`

did it.

```
mysql -u root -p --default-character-set=utf8 dtbs < 1.sql
```